# TYPO3 - Upgrade V9.5.31 to V10.4.21 Error

Tags: typo3-10.x

Upgrade V9.5.31 to V10.4.21 (Frontend Error)

(1/1) GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException 
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4020:805::200a: Network is unreachable (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
**Does anyone know why TYPO3 does not recognize the class?**

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the backend in 'Configure Installation-Wide Options' and change
the following value from true to false: `[HTTP][verify] = false;`

This should fix the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).